# C++ unordered map with uint8_t

Tags: c++, stl, unordered-map

I'm having a strange problem using an unordered_map with key type `uint64_t` and value type `uint8_t`. (I have a few potentially large integers that I want to count with the `uint8_t` values.) Here's some code:

```
std::unordered_map<uint64_t,uint8_t> mymap;
mymap.emplace(2,1);
mymap.emplace(20,3);
mymap.emplace(200,34);

for (auto it = mymap.begin(); it != mymap.end(); ++it) {
    std::cout << it->first << ":" << it->second << std::endl;
    printf("%lld : %d\n", it->first, it->second);
}
```

It appears that the keys and values are saved perfectly fine in the `unordered_map`. But, the `std::cout << it->second << std::endl;` code is garbling the output of the `uint8_t` values. That is,  `cout` (the first line in the for loop) garbles the output, while the old school cstdio `printf` (the second line in the for loop) prints out the values just fine. Weird. Any idea as to what is happening here?

If I change the `unordered_map` to `<uint64_t,uint16_t>` or `<uint64_t,int>`, it works perfectly fine. I've tried various terminal and pseudo terminal environments plus text files, all with garbled or missing outputs for the `uint8_t`s. I'm stumped.

Here is the output:

```
20:
20 : 3
200:"
200 : 34
2:
2 : 1
```

Comment: Care to add a garbled pair or two?

Comment: hint: what is `uint8_t` a typedef of?

Answer (score 2):

Note: There are no formatted input functions taking a signed or unsigned char in the iostream library. Hence the the uint8_t is converted and interpreted as character.

`std::cout << it->first << ":" << ùnsigned(it->second) << std::endl;` will fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a cast:

```
std::cout << int(it->second);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that type `uint8_t` is an alias for type `unsigned char`. If you will cast the value to unsigned int you will get the same result as with printf.

```
for (auto it = mymap.begin(); it != mymap.end(); ++it) {
    std::cout << it->first << ":" << ( unsigned int )it->second << std::endl;
    printf("%lld : %d\n", it->first, it->second);
}
```

As for your original code there is used the following operator for `uint8_t`

```
template<class traits>
basic_ostream<char,traits>& operator<<(basic_ostream<char,traits>&,
unsigned char);
```